# Configure Apache2 and tomcat7 with mod_jk

Tags: linux, apache2, tomcat7

I want to configure  Apache2 and tomcat7 with mod_jk in Linux environment ..I want to know the steps ..Please help me to congure it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything yourself?

http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html should get you going. But if you have not tried anything yet how can we help you then? Let use know if anything specific goes wrong, including error messages etc.

Comment: when i am running following cmd...Linux window is getting closed.
 ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs

Comment: There is probably no need to compile it yourself. What distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configuration for the apache (i use CentOS). The first file is under /etc/httpd/conf/wokers.properties

```
# the name tomcat1 is variable
worker.list=tomcat1
# default ajp port on server.xml of tomcat
worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tocmat1.socket_timeout=200
worker.tomcat1.retries=1
```

The second file depends on whether global or want Customizing for a virtual host. The following example is based on a virtual host (/etc/httpd/conf/virtualhost.conf)

```
JkWorkersFile "/etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile /var/log/httpd/jk.log
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
JkLogLevel info

# mount all under URI /
JkMount /* tomcat1

# umount /robots.txt, request goes to apache document root
JkMount /robots.txt tomcat1
```